# Using BufferedReader to call same file in 2 separate classes gives FileNotFoundException (Access is denied)

Tags: java, debugging, bufferedreader

So I'm trying to create a simple Bank application for a school project. My Authenticate class takes the username and password entered in my GUI and reads the file associated with the username using BufferedReader.

```
public Authenticate(String user, String pw){
    username = user;
    password = pw;
}
public void Login() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    try (BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileLocation+username))) {
        String i;

        //Checking password
        i=read.readLine();
        pass = password.equals(i);
        //Checking if user is admin
        i=read.readLine();
        isAdmin = "manager".equals(i);
    }

}
```

Where fileLocation is "C:\Users\rayle\Desktop\FinalProject\BankProject\" and username is let's say cat. Then the first line in the file is the password, second line is customer or manager and third line is how much money they have in the account. THIS PART WORKS FINE.

```
public Balance(String user){
    username = user;
}
public String getBalance() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    try (BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileLocation+username))) {
        String last=null, line;
        while((line=read.readLine()) != null){
            last = line;
        }   currentBal = last;
    }
    return currentBal;
}
```

So this second class just wants to read the amount in the account but whenever I try, I get this java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\rayle\Desktop\FinalProject\BankProject (Access is denied). If I use (fileLocation+"cat") in the BufferedReader, the program works fine though.

Comment: You should always close resources before exiting the program as it might cause issues when you reopen.

Comment: Do you mean something like read.close()? I've tried that and it gives the exact same error

Comment: @Nivedita Unless the app is closing abnormally, `try-with-resources` should be closing the files after it leaves the `try` block

Comment: Did you pass the correct username to your `Balance` constructor?  It certainly appears `username`, which was set by the constructor, is blank when you are calling `getBalance()`.

Comment: @Kevin Anderson It's correct. I get the username value from my GUI and I've tested that as well so it's not that I'm trying to call a different file or anything like that.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh yes! I missed the try with resources code.

Comment: Well, then, something must have set the `username` member of your `Balance` instance to an empty string sometime between when it was constructed (supposedly with the correct username) and the time you called `getBalance()`, because the filename you're opening has just the file location.  Or maybe you've got **two instances** of `Balance` and one of them was constructed with an empty username and _that's_ the one you're calling `getBalance()` on...

Comment: @KevinAnderson I did the exact same thing with Balance as I did with Authenticate so I don't think that's the problem. In theory if I close the BufferedReader, I should be able to open it back up again and read the same file, but my problem is I get access denied

Comment: Think about why `fileLocation+"cat"` works, but `fileLocation+username` doesn't. How could that occur? Answer that question  and you'll be on your way to a solution.

Answer (score -2):

You need to close the resource after doing what you want.Then you can reopen it. My recommendation is, when you open the resource, used data-structures to do data processing what you want.

Comment: The OP's code shows that he/she is using **Try With Resources**. It should close automatically once the **try** block is done.